# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value after returning from function

Tags: c, function, pointers

In my program, I want to get rid of non-alphabetical characters.
They are written in char*pattern. It is done in function. In function, I've got no problem to print it out but after returning I'm getting a warning:
***Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)***

It looks like: the text is:  `co*asd`

```
   printf("%s\n", pattern); // printed normally line 149
   pattern = scan_opt_patern(pattern, &extra_character, //line150
            &letter_before, pattern_len);  //line 151
   printf("%s\n", pattern); // printed with cond jump //line 152
```

Second printf prints text correctly without missing any blank space but gives conditional jump error.

Function is:

```
char *scan_opt_patern(char *pattern, char *extra_character, 
    char *letter_before, int pateren_len)
{
  int counter_of_position = 0, pos_extra;
  char pattern_without_ex[pateren_len - 1];
  while (*(pattern + counter_of_position)){
    if (*(pattern + counter_of_position) == '+' ||
       *(pattern + counter_of_position) == '*' ||
        *(pattern + counter_of_position) == '?'){
      *(extra_character) = *(pattern + counter_of_position);
      *(letter_before) = *(pattern + counter_of_position - 1);
      pos_extra = counter_of_position -1;
    }
    if (*(extra_character) != '0')
      pattern_without_ex[counter_of_position] = *(pattern + counter_of_position+1);
    else
      pattern_without_ex[counter_of_position] = *(pattern + counter_of_position);

    counter_of_position ++;
  }
  pattern = pattern_without_ex;
  printf("%s.\n", pattern); // always printed without problem
  return pattern;
}
```

Valgrind prints:

```
==11983== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==11983==    at 0x483EF49: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:461)
==11983==    by 0x48DEE94: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1688)
==11983==    by 0x48C7EBE: printf (printf.c:33)
==11983==    by 0x4016F7: check_if_match (try.c:152)
==11983==    by 0x4017BA: search_in_text (try.c:233)
==11983==    by 0x401403: main (try.c:72)
```

Comment: Not sure I follow ... what or where is the "conditional jump"?

Comment: Can you create [mcve]?

Comment: I've edited the desciption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `scan_opt_patern()` you do

```
 char pattern_without_ex[pateren_len - 1];
 ...
 pattern = pattern_without_ex;
 ...
 return pattern;
```

so you're returning the address of a variable that has become out of scope when the function returns and that invokes Undefined Behaviour.

You have several options:

1. pass a buffer for `pattern_without_ex` to the function
2. allocate the memory with `malloc()` and call `free()` in the calling function when you don't need the value any more
3. (discouraged) use a `static` variable